# Why is bower outputting JSON to the command line

Tags: bower

Recently, whenever I try to use Bower in my SSH terminal I get all responses returned in a JSON format.

The first image is of a simple bower command. This usually renders all the options in a formatted version, not JSON.

The second image is of the bower install command. Once again, it usually renders the output in a standard format and not JSON.

[image: bower command example]
[image]

Here is my .bowerrc file

```js
{
  "directory": "vendor",
  "json": "bower.json"
}
```

Comment: See if you've got a `.bowerrc` file somewhere - in your project folder, or in your home, perhaps.

Comment: @ceejayoz I've added my .bowerrc file to the post but nothing in there appears to be the issue. I cannot seem to find a config options about the output either on [bower](http://bower.io/docs/config/)

Comment: Pretty sure your `"json": "bower.json"` is doing the same as a CLI `--json` flag instead of what you think it will. http://bower.io/docs/api/#json

Comment: I'll make that my answer, then. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"json": "bower.json"` in your `.bowerrc` isn't doing what you think it's doing. It's doing the same as `"json": true` and triggering Bower's `--json` config option that enables JSON output.

http://bower.io/docs/api/#json